# proper use of nestedExpr in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a nested representation of key values pairs something like:
Case 1:

```
str = " value 23"
```

Case 2:

```
str = " value { \
          {'name' {value 'joint'}}, 
          {'id' {value 51}} \
         }"
```

Or case 3:

```
str = " value { \
           { 'drive' { value 'joint1'}}, \
           { 'steer' { value 45.35}}
         }"
```

As can be seen, the nesting can go to unlimited levels. e.g. in above example, `'joint2'` can have curly braces as well. `value` is the only keyword here. Lastly, the values can be integers, floats or single quoted strings.

I have a very simple code here:

```
field_name = Keyword("value").supress()
real = Combine(Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums))
values = real | Word(
    nums) | sglQuotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)

nested = nestedExpr('{', '}')
grammar = field_name + \
    (values | (nestedExpr('{', '}') + Optional(',').suppress()))("values")
```

for case 2, I get an output

```
{'values': [[["'name'", ['value', "'joint'"]], ',', ["'id'", ['value', '51']]]]}
```

Firstly the `','` and `value` are being parsed as well. Secondly I am not sure if I am using `nestedExpr`  correctly. Should I be using `Dict` inside `nestedExpr`?

**Edit 1:**
I have already posted the solution for above cases, but I realized case 2 and 3 are identical. What I actually wanted to show was

Case 4:

```
str = "value { \
         {'name' {value 'joint1' { \
                           value 12} \
                                 } \
                 } \
         }, \
         {'id' {value 51}} \
       }"
```

For such cases do I need to know how deep is the nesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution:

```
from pyparsing import *

_value = Keyword("value").suppress()
real = Combine(Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums))
values = real | Word(
    nums) | sglQuotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)


LCB, RCB = map(Suppress, "{}")
param_val = _value + values
param_vals = Dict(OneOrMore(Group(sglQuotedString.setParseAction(
    removeQuotes) + nestedExpr('{', '}', content=param_val))))
param_values = _value + \
    nestedExpr('{', '}', content=delimitedList(
        LCB + param_vals + RCB, delim=','))

str = "value {{'name' {value 'arm_right_1_joint'}}, {'id' {value 51}}}"
res = param_values.parseString(str)

print(res.dump())
```

I get the result:

```
[[['name', ['arm_right_1_joint']], ['id', ['51']]]]
[0]:
  [['name', ['arm_right_1_joint']], ['id', ['51']]]
  - id: ['51']
  - name: ['arm_right_1_joint']
```

Please feel free to suggest other solutions.

**Edit:**
I found an even better solution. Now it can parse any level of recursiveness.

```
real = Combine(Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums))

listStr = Forward()
mapStr = Forward()
param_value = Forward()

string_value = Dict(Group(sglQuotedString.setParseAction(
    removeQuotes) + ZeroOrMore(LCB + param_value + RCB)))
string_value.setParseAction(parseActionStr)
values = Combine(Optional("-") + real) | Combine(Optional("-") + Word(
    nums)) | string_value | Keyword("false") | Keyword("true") | listStr | mapStr
listStr << delimitedList(Group(LCB + delimitedList(values) + RCB))

mapStr << (LSB + delimitedList(Group(LCB + delimitedList((Group(sglQuotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes) +
                                                                Suppress(":") + values))) + RCB)) + RSB)
mapStr.setParseAction(parseActionDict)

param_value << _value + (values | listStr)
```

And the results for:

```
str_param4 = "value { \
                  {'type' {value 'laser'}}, \
                  {'params' {value { \
                      {'upper_replacement_value' {value 10.0}}, \
                      {'use_message_range_limits' {value false}}, \
                      {'upper_threshold' {value 10.0}}}, \
                  {'name' {value 'range'}}}}}"
```

are:

```
[['laser']]
[['range']]
[[[['type', 'laser']], [['params', [[['upper_replacement_value', '10.0']], [['use_message_range_limits', 'false']], [['upper_threshold', '10.0']]], [['name', 'range']]]]]]
[0]:
  [[['type', 'laser']], [['params', [[['upper_replacement_value', '10.0']], [['use_message_range_limits', 'false']], [['upper_threshold', '10.0']]], [['name', 'range']]]]]
  [0]:
    [['type', 'laser']]
    - type: 'laser'
  [1]:
    [['params', [[['upper_replacement_value', '10.0']], [['use_message_range_limits', 'false']], [['upper_threshold', '10.0']]], [['name', 'range']]]]
    - params: [[[['upper_replacement_value', '10.0']], [['use_message_range_limits', 'false']], [['upper_threshold', '10.0']]], [['name', 'range']]]
      [0]:
        [[['upper_replacement_value', '10.0']], [['use_message_range_limits', 'false']], [['upper_threshold', '10.0']]]
        [0]:
          [['upper_replacement_value', '10.0']]
          - upper_replacement_value: '10.0'
        [1]:
          [['use_message_range_limits', 'false']]
          - use_message_range_limits: 'false'
        [2]:
          [['upper_threshold', '10.0']]
          - upper_threshold: '10.0'
      [1]:
        [['name', 'range']]
        - name: 'range'
```

Comment: Nice use of `Dict` to auto-define the results names. I generally discourage using `nestedExpr` for much more than just matching nested open/close delimiters (usually for just skipping over them when trying to parse some larger expression), but with your added definition of content, probably OK. If you use `pyparsing_common.number` in `values` in place of `real` and `Word(nums)` you'll get some faster-parsing Regex exprs, plus auto-conversion to actual Python floats and ints.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @PaulMcG!! I am still unable to handle nested structures. Is there a good way of doing that? Or I need to know beforehand how many levels of nesting I am expecting?

Comment: For unlimited nesting, we'll need to do a more proper recursive parser. *Might* be doable with `nestedExpr`, but writing an explicit recurser using `Forward` will be the better choice. At this point, I would step back and write out a BNF to clarify thinking on how the nesting is going to go - then translate back into pyparsing/Python.